# Problem populating pageBlockTable with data from custom object through custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, pageblocktable

In a controller I'm populating a list of objects:

```
public with sharing class SubmittalDashboard {

    public list<Show__c> missingShow {get; set;}

    public void SubmittalDashboard() {

        for (Show__c s : [select Show_Display_Name__c from Show__c]) {
            missingShow.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

On a VisualForce page, I'd like to display the contents of the list `missingShow` in a pageBlockTable:

```
<apex:page controller="SubmittalDashboard">
<apex:pageBlock title="Missing Submittals">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!missingShow}" var="s">
         <apex:column value="{!s.Show_Display_Name__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

When I load everything in and go to the VF page, the table shows up blank -- the title is there but there is no data.  When I execute the controller anonymous with debug logging from  inside Eclipse, I see that the right data is being added to the `missingShow` list. So the controller has the right data, but for some reason its not getting to the VF page.

This is the first time I'm using pageBlockTable with a custom controller, so I'm hoping someone out there sees something totally obvious that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has `SubmittalDashboard` as a method rather than a constructor so `missingShow` remains null. Before adding to a list you have to create a new instance of it so once you fixed constructor your would get a null pointer exception when you invoked `add`.

This would be a simpler version of your code:

```
public with sharing class SubmittalDashboard {

    public list<Show__c> missingShow {get; set;}

    public SubmittalDashboard() {
        missingShow = [select Show_Display_Name__c from Show__c];
    }
}
```

The Visualforce looks OK.

Comment: Yup, that did it! Of course, no return type for a constructor! Silly error, which I knew it was when I was posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more of your application, another solution is to do a lazy fetch of `missingShow` only when the VF page needs it such as in this code snippet:

```
public List<Show__c> missingShow {
  get{
       if (this.missingShow == null) {
          this.missingShow = [select show_display_name__c from Show__c];
       }
       return this.missingShow;
     }
  private set;
}
```